# sudo: USER variable not set to effective user on RHEL 7.5 - why?

Tags: sudo, aix, rhel, suse, sles

I am currently having a sudo problem and hope you can give me a hint where I have to look for...

**Where do I have to configure sudo on RHEL 7.5 that USER variable is set to effective user?**

Currently I am searching where the difference between sudo config on RHEL vs. AIX & SuSE is. (Sorry, I am not keen on configuring sudo and I can not see an obvious difference between /etc/sudoers on RHEL compared to AIX/SuSE...)

Only on RHEL sudo does not set USER variable to root as on AIX & SuSE.

RHEL:

> sudo ksh -c 'echo $USER'
>
> > **enkidu**

Why is USER not set to root?

AIX:

> sudo ksh -c 'echo $USER'
>
> > root

SuSE:

> sudo ksh -c 'echo $USER'
>
> > root

Tnx for your hints.

Regards,
Enkidu

Comment: Is there an `env_keep` in the configuration?

Comment: Another possibility would be if they *unset* set_logname

Comment: Has systemd integrated sudo yet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on unix.stackexchange.com